# how to return objects in array as string with comma ?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

var list = [ {
        id : 1234,
        shop : 'shop1'
    }, {
        id : 4312,
        shop : 'shop2'
    } ];

I want that only **id** attributes in object array return as **"1234,4312"**. How can I do?

Comment: pluck the ids in a loop, and then join them to a string by commata? Have you tried?

Comment: Divide it up into individual tasks. You want to get the id attributes of objects in an array, and you want to join several things with a comma. Which is these tasks do you not know how to do?

Comment: Yes, but it is not easy way. I want to find out easier and alternative methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even easier:

```
var list = [ { id : 1234, shop : 'shop1' }, { id : 4312, shop : 'shop2' } ];
ids = list.map(function(obj){
    return obj.id
})
```

If you specifically need a string, add a .toString() to the end of the map call:

```
ids = list.map(function(obj){
    return obj.id
}).toString()
```

Comment: OP requires the result to be a commadelimited string.

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through the array and create a new array. It's actually not that hard:

```
var list = [ { id : 1234, shop : 'shop1' }, { id : 4312, shop : 'shop2' } ];
var ids = [];
list.forEach(function(obj, index){
    ids.push(obj.id);
});
```

if you want that as a comma delimited string you can simply call `ids.toString();` it's the default behavior.

Comment: You really should use `map` instead of `forEach`. Also, OP requires the result to be a string.